# make rows distinct and total duplicate row values

Tags: php, mysql, distinct-values

I am trying to populate all invoices relating to a customer having a unique row per invoice - the **tval** column should add (sum) the total if the invoice number repeats, the total tval sum should be aliased as per the indicated **label** (column). there are only two types of labels "crn" & "acr" if both aren`t there then the value can be a Null

I tried so many ways to achieve this but i failed, this is the closest i could get

```
SELECT 
    i.si_num AS `id`,
    DATE_FORMAT(i.si_date, '%d-%b-%Y') AS `date`,
    i.si_tr AS `tr`,
    d.dl_name AS `customer`,
    i.si_net_value AS `net`,
    DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), si_date) AS Days,
    t.value AS tval,
    t.label AS label
FROM
    invoices AS i
LEFT JOIN
    dealer AS d ON i.si_tr = d.dl_id
LEFT JOIN
    transactions AS t ON i.si_num = t.invoice
WHERE
    i.si_tr = 'TR580494'
ORDER BY `si_num` DESC;
```

and this is the result i am getting 
[image]

Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

With you SQL statement, try to use DISTINCT on tval Example:

SELECT DISTINCT tval

Comment: Tried that doesn`t work that way, there are three things i am trying to achieve.

1. list all the records relating to customer, without duplicates
2. assign a seperate columns for "crn" and "acr" labels
3. total values of "crn" / "acr" as per invoice if they repeat.

I hope this isnt complicating

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
i.si_num AS `id`, DATE_FORMAT(i.si_date, '%d-%b-%Y') AS `date`,
i.si_tr AS `tr`, d.dl_name AS `customer`, i.si_net_value AS `net`,
DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), si_date) AS Days, SUM(t.value) AS tval,
GROUP_CONCAT(t.label) AS label
FROM invoices AS i
INNER JOIN dealer AS d ON i.si_tr = d.dl_id
INNER JOIN transactions AS t ON i.si_num = t.invoice
WHERE i.si_tr = 'TR580494'
GROUP BY id, date, tr, customer, net, Days
ORDER BY `si_num` DESC;
```

Comment: This results in showing the duplicates distinct. :/